# The sample code for admob on iPhone is not showing an ad

Tags: iphone, admob

My goal is to create an AdMob banner in my iPhone app.  As a starting point, all I want to do is sucessfully run the example code provided by Google.  I registered for an adMob account and got a publisher id.  I download the sample code provided by Google at http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/fundamentals.html.

I added the following to the top of my BannerExampleViewController.m:

```
#define MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID @"xxxxxxxxxxxxx3dc2"
```

The code runs without errors or warnings.  I don't see any messages on the console.  However, when I run in the Simulator (4.2) I get just a grey screen without the ad as shown in Google's screen shot.  The documentation advises that you have to wait 2 minutes the first time but I have waited longer than that and no joy.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Dessie.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps on that page? Did you add all of their files into your project? Did you add a GADBannerView as a subview to your view controller's view? The #define above will not do anything to your application. It just tells the compiler "Hey, when you are compiling, if you see MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID, replace that text with @"xxxxxxxxxxx3dc2" (which I assume you edited so we wouldn't see your ID, since the actual ID won't have all the x's in it)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I know it's a vague question.  I followed the steps as closely as I could.  I suspect that the bannerView is displaying, it's just off screen.  I added the following line to just after the GADBannerView is allocated:

Comment: NSLog(@"%d %d",bannerView_.center.x, bannerView_.center.y);.  I was expecting the response to be like 0 430 but the output on the console is 0 1080295424.  Isn't that weird?  If the second number refers to pixels it would be miles away from the viewable area.  I don't know what to make of it.  Also, you are right.  In my code the MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID value is an alphanumeric string, I just stuck in the xs to protect my privacy.

Answer (score 4):

So after an afternoon of goofing around, I seem to have solved my problem.  I just wanted to post my solution in case anyone got stuck at the same point.

When I ran the sample code as it is issued, I got a blank view with no error messages and no ad.  I probably should have put some NSLog messages in the AdBannerDidReceiveAd method or the error method and I would have gotten an answer sooner.  Anyway, the critical thing I did that got me rolling was to put my ad request in testing mode.  I did this by replacing the line:

```
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

with:

```
GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
r.testing = YES;
[bannerView_ loadRequest:r];
```

Full disclosure: I didn't just think of this, I found it on Mark's tech blog at:

http://markstechstuff.blogspot.com/2011/04/gadrequest-test-mode-istesting.html

Thanks Mark,

Dessie

Comment: yes, I discover the same thing by myself a few moments ago, but it did not solve my case.

Answer (score 0):

Call the below method in viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)addAdmob{
    bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeLargeBanner];
    bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-2256523967514###/##########";
    bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView];
    [bannerView loadRequest: [GADRequest request]];
}
```